# Exe give a error and it is closing. OGRE 3D Library

Tags: c++, ogre3d

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ocra.png]

How do I solve this problem ? I use Visual Studio .NET 2010.I installed DirectX 9.

Comment: Try to delete ogre.cfg. There might be stored some values for video mode that isn't supported on your system. Try another 3d games to make sure you have proper video drivers installed.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you should post the `OgreD3D9RenderSystem.cpp` and the code near to line 594 for other people to know what's going wrong.

As I assume, OGRE throws an exception when the requested video mode can't be somehow forced or is unavailable (this can happen due to hardware limitations).

Comment: Thanks for answer.But I don't found OgreD3D9RenderSystem.cpp.I found OgreD3D9RenderSystem.h file. ?

Answer (score 0):

Delete your *ogre.cfg* file and restart your application. You will now again see the Ogre configuration dialog. Choose a different screen resolution in the "video mode" option and try again.

Optionally you can also manually edit the *ogre.cfg* in a text editor of your choosing.

In case someone wants to have a look at the code, the [relevant part](https://bitbucket.org/sinbad/ogre/src/3cbd67467fab3fef44d1b32bc42ccf4fb1ccfdd0/RenderSystems/Direct3D9/src/OgreD3D9RenderSystem.cpp?at=default#cl-682) can be seen in the official Ogre BitBucket repository.